# Power Bi export to excel

Tags: powerbi, export, visualization

Hello i am new with power bi.
When i am no able to export visualization to excel, I only see the options Analyze in Excel, Power Point, and Pdf.
I check permissions in pbix file and and everything is ok.
Iam login as Power Bi Administrator
Thank you for help**

Comment: Look through [Export the data that was used to create a visualization](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/visuals/power-bi-visualization-export-data?tabs=powerbi-service), and see if the section "Admin and designer controls for exporting" is why.